# Defining $\mathbb{Z}_+$

Tags: set-theory

While reading Munkres' Topology section about integers and reals (Chapter 1, Section 4), he defines the set $\mathbb{Z}_+$ as:

> Definition: A subset $A$ of the real
>   numbers is said to be inductive if it
>   contains the number 1, and if for
>   every $x$ in $A$, the number $x+1$ is
>   also in $A$. Let $\cal{A}$ be the
>   collection of all inductive subsets of
>   $\mathbb{R}$. Then the set
>   $\mathbb{Z}_+$ of positive integers is
>   defined by the equation $\bigcap _{A
>   \in \cal{A}} A$

Isn't it possible to define $\mathbb{Z}_+$ as the set defined this way:

$1\in B \wedge (j \in B, n-1 = j) \Rightarrow n\in B$

Then $B = \mathbb{Z}_+$

Comment: This doesn't determine B as the set of positive integers. Basically you're just saying that B is an inductive set.

Comment: In fact, if you look at the definition you gave from Munkres's book, the set of positive integers being defined as the intersection of all inductive sets is just saying that the positive integers constitute a minimal inductive set.

Comment: Ohh, you're right. I thought the second definition excluded other non integers from appearing but actually B could be any inductive set. Thanks a lot!

Comment: fmartin: could you write that up as a community wiki answer, so that you can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Taking the intersection of all inductive sets is like taking the smallest inductive set. It's also like taking the minimal fixpoint of your other definition.

Comment: Carl: Sure, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting Adrián Barquero:

> This doesn't determine B as the set of
>   positive integers. Basically you're
>   just saying that B is an inductive
>   set. In fact, if you look at the
>   definition you gave from Munkres's
>   book, the set of positive integers
>   being defined as the intersection of
>   all inductive sets is just saying that
>   the positive integers constitute a
>   minimal inductive set.